# Display one image above and one below with less padding

Tags: html

I want to display two images in a `div` with one at the top and one on the bottom.

I have achieved this but there seems to be extra space especially at the bottom and I don't know where this comes from. When I use Firebug layout it show a height of 61 pixels but my images are only 18x16 and I think that doesn't include padding and margins which are just a few pixels in any case.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonfiddleboy/9dQs6/)

```
<div class="ex6">
  <img src="images/uparrow.png" align="top" id="Z6Sync" width="18" height="16" title="up" onclick="manualup()" alt="up"><p>
  <img src="images/downarrow.png" id="Z6Sync" width="18" height="16" title="up" onclick="manualup()" alt="down">
</div>
```

**css**

```
div.ex6
{
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:1px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  border:2px;
  font-size:0.7em;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#ddd;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:right;
  background: #eee;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hS4Hc/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the `<p>` tag you added after the first image. A paragraph has a fixed style that includes a margin/padding after the paragraph. Get rid of it and take care of adding the line break via CSS to make sure the images are shown one below the other.

To achieve this you can for example set the images inside of your image to be displayed as block element:

```
div.ex6 img { display: block }
```

If you do that, you will have to add some more styling though to add some more margins, especially between the images. You do could do it like this:

```
div.ex6 img:first-child { margin-bottom: 5px }
```

But there are also many other ways, including just using `<br />` instead of `<p>`. I personally don't like using manual line breaks for positioning though.